# Slideshow in Angularjs doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am new to using angularjs and I wanted to try it out by using it to create a continuous slideshow of content. I was able to get the slide to work for about a day by using a contributor on this site as a reference.

However the next day I began working on it the slide stopped working. My images wouldn't even display. After fiddling with the code I found that removing "ng-app" from the html tag allowed the images to appear again but still the code will not run.

Code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  lang="en" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl as app" >
<head>
<link href="css/test.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script data-require="angular.min.js@1.7.9"src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
    <style>
     .evt-title {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 38%;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  top: -15px;
}

.evtslide {
  /*width:100%;
    height:400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;*/
  right: 0;
  height: 690px;
  width: 26.7%;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.evtslide .slider-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 690px;
  background: url("../images/bluebg2.png");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.evtslide .slider-content2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 690px;
  background: url("../images/graybg2.png");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.animate-enter, .animate-leave {
  -webkit-transition: 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) all;
  transition: 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) all;
}

.animate-enter {
  left: 100%;
}

.animate-enter.animate-enter-active {
  left: 0;
}

.animate-leave {
  left: 0;
}

.animate-leave.animate-leave-active {
  left: -100%;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=test.css.map */


 </style

</head>
<body>




<div ng-controller="slideShowController" class="evtslide" ng-switch='slideshow' ng-animate="'animate'">
  <div class="slider-content" ng-switch-when="1">
    <h3 class="evt-title">EVENTS</h3>

  </div>    
  <div class="slider-content2" ng-switch-when="2">
    <h3 class="evt-title">EVENTS</h3>

  </div>
  <div class="slider-content" ng-switch-when="3">
    <h3 class="evt-title">EVENTS</h3>

  </div>        
  <div class="slider-content2" ng-switch-when="4">
    <h3 class="evt-title">EVENTS</h3>

  </div>




 <script>
function slideShowController($scope, $timeout) {
    var slidesInSlideshow = 4;
    var slidesTimeIntervalInMs = 3000; 

    $scope.slideshow = 1;
    var slideTimer =
    $timeout(function interval() {
        $scope.slideshow = ($scope.slideshow % slidesInSlideshow) + 1;
        slideTimer = $timeout(interval, slidesTimeIntervalInMs);
        }, slidesTimeIntervalInMs);
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: - no need for ng-switch angularjs will provide a 2way databind so just do switching in your controller <br>
-remove all duplicate code <div class slider_content/2/ make an object with the styles associated for each slide
-put your ng-animate on each slide and not the slide container
change interval to $interval. =>
Use the angularJs `$interval` service just like you are doing with `$timeout`

see examples below

Comment: do not remove `ng-app` . ng-app tells angular "hey angular here is an app called `myApp` can you implement its logic from a controller called `AppCtrl` "

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.9/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <img src={{slide_image}} />
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {

  var slide_images = ["image_1.jpeg","image_2.jpeg","image_3.jpeg","image_4.jpeg"]; 
  $scope.slide_image = slide_images[0];
  var i=1;  
  $interval(function () {
    $scope.slide_image = slide_images[i%slide_images.length];
    i++;
  }, 1000);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The rest is css
To do more such as add text, change animation etc. make `$scope.slide_images` an array of objects with the properties you want. Each object can then contain its own: image, style, behavior etc you can go crazy with customization.. 
The above code is here as a [demo](http://timetrax.co/sandbox/angularJs_slideshow/index.html)